# PHP Paypal, without account?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a client who needs a donation system done (doesn't care with what system, just needs it to work) and it needs to be in PHP. I know that one can use PayPal to do this. However, the first problem is I do not know (and doubt) if the client has a PayPal business account or not, is it a good idea to create one to test it? Now, I know this might be a RTM question, but, is it possible to not care about how much money has been donated and not use IPN? I need as low complexity as possible.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the last sentence about not caring how much has been donated, and not using IPN.

Comment: AFAIK, IPN is for confirming that the transaction occurred, correct? So, can I just not care?

Comment: @Dhaivat then this may be the very, very easiest way: https://www.paypal.com/en/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_donate-intro-outside be aware of the pricing structure though, PayPal charge heavily.

Comment: What do you mean? PayPal actually charges me money for each donation? Sorry if missed some sarcasm.

Comment: @Dhaivat Huh? As far as I know, PayPal has no special pricing for donations. Standard charges apply.

Comment: **Edit:** There *are* reduced fees for charities, but apparently only for US registered ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to setup and start integrating Paypal in your app/web site, you may create a paypal developer account:
https://developer.paypal.com/

EDIT: as noted in the comments, it's https://www.x.com/index.jspa now

You then have a sandbox in which you may test all PayPal transactions.

It may take more than a minute to create an account, last time I used it, it was very slow.

Of course I'd first check with your client whether she already uses or really wants to use Paypal in the future.

Comment: When you have a company buying a *single letter domain* to host their *developer API* on, you know they are making too much money.

Comment: @Pekka i know i was thinking the exact samething